# Reacts Js : problem parsing wordpress page

Tags: json, reactjs, wordpress

Hello i'm new on this language and i'm having some problems about parsing wordpress page with reactjs.

After parsing correctly page list inside class

```
componentDidMount(){

let projectUrl = "/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/";
fetch(projectUrl)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    this.setState({
        projects: response
    })
})
}
```

than the render of the json with a map (in this sample i am rendering the post content with html plus)

```
render(){


let projects = this.state.projects.map((project, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: project.content.rendered }} />
        </div>
    )
    })

 return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        {projects}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but if a need to extract only one page with specific id (ex 1)

```
let projectUrl = "/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1";
```

the response of json is not an array of array but it seem a string only(or i can't understand the output).

How i can parse the "simplified" json and return output ?

Comment: If you hit a roadblock on this you can always set up a custom endpoint for the WP json and pass back whatever format you choose.

Comment: But if i need to parse only string?

Comment: Why not assign projects as an array and push this.state.projects to it? `let projects = []; projects.push(this.state.projects); this.state.projects.map(...)`